# While process is not running, do something

Tags: loops, process, while-loop

```
while ps aux | grep '[/]pathtoprocess'
do
echo Running
done
echo Process Finished
```

I use this shell script to keep running while a certain process is running.
What I would like to do now is to do the same while that certain process is NOT running.

How would I go about it?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
x=$(ps aux | grep '[/]pathtoprocess')

while false
do
echo Not Running
done
```

==========================================================================

## New Script

```
#!/bin/ksh

if ps -aux | grep "[/]$1"
then
    echo "Running"
else
    echo "Not Running"
    #do your stuff
    # you can add while loop here 
    #echo "process Finished
fi
```

### Output:

```
./iCheck.sh xyz
Not Running

./iCheck.sh usr/bin/cron
Running
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this doesn't work, the process isn't running so it should echo Not Running. However it runs the script without this echo.

Comment: also try without `[/]`; just as `if ps -aux | grep "$1"`